# Change terminal tab name when running a command on package.json

Tags: node.js, bash, iterm2

I have multiple apps that need to be run at the same time, but it's complicated keeping up with which one is which in the terminal. Is there a way that I can rename their respective tabs through the command on `package.json`?

The area with the scripts looks something like this right now:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "app1:dev": "[SCRIPT_TO_NAME_TAB] && cd app1 && nodemon server",
     "app2:dev": "[SCRIPT_TO_NAME_TAB] && cd app2 && nodemon server",
     "app3:dev": "[SCRIPT_TO_NAME_TAB] && cd app3 && nodemon server",
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there anything I can replace on `[SCRIPT_TO_NAME_TAB]` with so that the tab is properly named whenever I run each of these scripts on my `package.json`? Thanks!

Edit: To add more to this I have found other threads that suggest I use something like

```sh
echo -n -e "\033]0;MY TITLE\007"
```

Unfortunately, that is not working and I get an error on the package.json file. So anyone know what is going on there?

Comment: Can you share the json file and the error message ?

Comment: Turns out the error message had to do with lacking an escape slash. Looks like it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case that I ended up lacking some escape slash. So for me to get it to work, in `package.json` scripts I did the following:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "app1:dev": "echo -n -e \"\\033]0;MY TITLE\\007\" && cd app1 && nodemon server",
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```